# Generating multiple random double numbers in a range, with Java?

Tags: java, random

I have done some research but I cannot find a working way for me to generate 9 random doubles in a range of (0 - 0.75).

I also need to add all 9 random numbers together for further calculations. I'm using DrJava.

So far from what I have tried, I only get one random number that repeats 9 times.

```
    double minLight = 0.0; 
    double maxLight = 0.75; 
    double totalSum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    double monday = (Math.random() * (maxLight - minLight) + minLight);
    double mRounded = Math.round(monday * 100.0) / 100.0;
    totalSum += mRounded;  
    }

    double mWalk = totalSum + shortestWalk;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    double wednesday = (Math.random() * (maxLight - minLight) + minLight);
    double wRounded = Math.round(wednesday * 100.0) / 100.0;
    System.out.println(wRounded);
    totalSum += wRounded;
    }

    double wWalk = totalSum + shortestWalk;         
    System.out.println(mWalk);
    System.out.println(wWalk);

Out Printed:
0.04
0.05
0.52
0.72
0.59
0.05
0.73
0.15
0.38
6.287142857142857
9.517142857142856
```

Comment: You are printing the same value four times. Better use a loop and generate the random number each time in the loop before printing.

Comment: Please stop using Javascript snippets to format your Java code.

Comment: Ok, what should i use? Im not sure because i don't see any Java box.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a double within `[least, bound)` range you can use the [`ThreadLoacalRandom.nextDouble(least, bound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextDouble(double,%20double)) method.

```
for (int i = 0; i< 3 ; i++) {
  double d = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(-0.75, 0);
  System.out.println(d);
}
```

Comment: @BoristheSpider because Java architects haven't added this and `nextInt(least, bound)` methods to standard `Random`. No idea why, only `ThreadLocalRandom` has them.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ThreadLocalRandom.nextDouble()` but that is not designed for your requirement : generating a random double inside a range with **no multithreading consideration**.

Indeed its javadoc says :

> Use of ThreadLocalRandom is particularly appropriate when multiple
>   tasks (for example, each a ForkJoinTask) use random numbers in
>   parallel in thread pools.

With `Random` you could get the right result and that appears less expensive in terms of overhead :

```
public double nextDouble() {
        return (((long)(next(26)) << 27) + next(27)) * DOUBLE_UNIT;
}
```

Use it such as :

```
Random r = new Random();
Double min = 0.0;
Double max = 0.75;
for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
    double randomValue = min + (max - min) * r.nextDouble();
    System.out.println(randomValue);
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for that. Did you refer about the seed performance difference ?

Comment: Ah sure but  in the actual question, is that point matter ?  If yes don't hesitate to point out that :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this function instead:

```
public double generateRandomDouble(double min, double max) {
    double x = (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    return Math.round(x * 100.0) / 100.0;
}
```

Each time you call it, you will get a random double. The parameters are your min and max. So this:

```
generateRandomDouble(0.0, 0.75);
```

Will return 1 random double. All you need to do is call the function 9 times. As such:

```
double sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    sum += generateRandomDouble(0.0, 0.75);
}

System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
```

This should be what you were looking for.

> The sum is: 1.98

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop to generate and print new number,

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
 double x = (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
 double xrounded = Math.round(x * 100.0) / 100.0;
 System.out.println(xrounded); 
}
```